# having trouble with range union method

Tags: excel, vba, union

Having trouble with vba using range Union method. I have resolved it, at the end. But could not find the proper explanation, why it is so?

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng00 = Range("A1:C3")
Set rng01 = Range("F1:G3")
ws.Union(rng00,rng01).Copy 'the error giving line
```

When I have changed the line with below one strangely it has started to work. But as I remember I have used union method of range before with ThisWorkbook(or maybe Workbooks(name))

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.Union(rng00,rng01).Copy
```

Comment: `Set rng00 = ws.Range("A1:C3")` and `Set rng01 = ws.Range("F1:G3")`

Comment: And remove the `ws.` from `ws.Union(rng00,rng01).Copy`

Comment: So you mean=> union(rng00,rng01).Copy ? Why? My main question is why

Comment: The parent sheet is passed in from the range objects.  The ranges in the Union all must be on the same sheet to work.

Comment: It does not work so

Comment: what is the error?  did you do all three things I proposed: `Set rng00 = ws.Range("A1:C3")` and `Set rng01 = ws.Range("F1:G3")` and `Union(rng00,rng01).Copy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Application.Union` feat. Qualifying Object References

**Your 1st Code**

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng00 = Range("A1:C3")
Set rng01 = Range("F1:G3")
ws.Union(rng00,rng01).Copy 'the error giving line
```

**Your 2nd Code**

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Application.Union(rng00,rng01).Copy
```

[`Application.ThisWorkbook property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook)

- `ThisWorkbook` is (a reference to) **the workbook containing this code**. It is an exact workbook and there can only be one of it.

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  ```

**Qualifying Worksheets**

- When referencing the sheets in a workbook, you want to qualify them (note the `wb.`):

  ```
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ```
- This can be only one worksheet, the worksheet named `Sheet1` in the `wb` - workbook. It can't be the wrong worksheet unless you have incorrectly referenced the workbook.
- When you do `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`, it creates a reference to any sheet (worksheet, chart) that is currently active (selected, you're looking at), yet in the line `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate` you are activating `Sheet1˛` of the `ActiveWorkbook`, the workbook which is the currently active (could be `ThisWorkbook`, but may not).

**Qualifying Ranges**

- When referencing the ranges in a worksheet, you want to qualify them (note the `ws.`):

  ```
  Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = ws.Range("A1:C3")
  Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = ws.Range("F1:G3")
  ```
- These are ranges in the `ws` - worksheet. They can't be the wrong ones unless you have incorrectly referenced the worksheet.
- When you do `Set rng00 = Range("A1:C3"): Set rng01 = Range("F1:G3")`, you are creating references to ranges of the `ActiveSheet` (could be a worksheet, could be a chart), of the `ActiveWorkbook` (could be `ThisWorkbook`, but may not). It would have worked correctly only by chance in case your `ActiveWorkbook` was `ThisWorkbook` and your `ActiveSheet` was a worksheet named `Sheet1` in the `ActiveWorkbook`.

[`Application.Union method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)

- Its 'full name' says it all: it's a member of the `Application` object, not the `Worksheet` object. You can omit the `Application.` part from some of the `Application` object members: `Union` is such a member.

  ```
  Union(rng1, rng2).Copy
  ```

**Alltogether**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRange()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = ws.Range("A1:C3")
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = ws.Range("F1:G3")
    Union(rng1, rng2).Copy
End Sub
```

- Of course, if there is no worksheet named `Sheet1` in the workbook, an error will occur. But that's another story.

Comment: Just Bravo! Great explanation that I was in desperate need of. I not only took a short lesson of union method's object belonging to Application, also declaring in one line. Thanks @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

`Union` is a function of the `Application` Object, not of a Worksheet Object. Which means that `ws.Union` would not work because there is no member with the name `Union` as a member of `ws`. The correct parent is `Application.Union` but since it would be tedious to write `Application.` for every function, most of the time the `Application.` is not written.

The arguments of `Union` must be Range Objects that are from the same Worksheet. When declaring Ranges, it is important to explicitly declare their parent sheet, to avoid issues later with functions like `Union`. Adding `ws` in front of `Range` like `ws.Range` is how you can declare that the range is a member of that sheet.

So the full corrected code would be

```vb
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng00 = ws.Range("A1:C3")
Set rng01 = ws.Range("F1:G3")
Application.Union(rng00, rng01).Copy
```